# Can I force 32 bit VBA references in my Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I use an Excel macro to update information on a 32 bit application via its API.
It works well on my PC, but it crashes on someone else's PC. 
Opening the VB editor in Excel (Alt F11) > Tools > References, I noticed that a number of Windows DLL and TLB files are located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (64 bit version).
e.g. stdole2.tlb (OLE Automation)
I want to force the 32 bit version, which is the same file in C:\Windows\System32

However when I disable the 64 bits reference and use the Browse button to add e.g. C:\Windows\System32\stdole2.tlb, the selected reference is not added to the list.

Is there a workaround to force this?

Note: the Excel I'm using is 2013, 32 bit version

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken SysWOW64 isn't the 64-bit version, it would be where 32-bit libraries are registered on a 64-bit Windows.

Comment: If the other person is using 64-bit Excel I'm not sure you can automate a different 32-bit application from VBA.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/), I understand that SysWOW64 actually stores 32 bit DLL, whilst System32 stores 64 bit libraries.

I copied the explanation below:

> On a 64-bit computer [...] the system-wide C:\Windows\System32 folder contains 64-bit libraries. 32-bit programs store their files in C:\Program Files (x86), and the system-wide folder is C:\Windows\SysWOW64.
>   This is definitely counterintuitive. Despite the “32” in the name, **the System32 folder contains 64-bit libraries**. And, despite the 64 in the name, **the SysWOW64 folder contains 32-bit libraries**—at least on 64-bit versions of Windows.